# How do I extract specific content?

Tags: python, nslookup

I'm trying to use nslookup on IP address and print only a part of it,
but when i use `ip_arr.append(data.replace('name =  ',''))` I end up with `'106.176.233.64.in-addr.arpa\tname = yw-in-f106.1e100.net.'` instead of `name = yw-in-f106.1e100.net.`

This is the main code:

```
for data in output:
    if 'name' in data:
        ip_arr.append(data.replace('name =  ',''))

print 'IP Address 1 : ', a
print 'Hostname  : ' , ip_arr
```

Comment: Show your entire code; it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: please update your question with sample input and required output